# For loop works, but For Each does not. Why?

Tags: java, arrays

There is an outofbounds exception being thrown on the line containing the forEach loop, but as far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with this code. The for loop is starting with element 0 of the char array and looping through until it reaches the last element... But when I try this code using a longer for loop, i.e.,

```
 for(int i = 0; i < nested.length; i++)
```

the code works as expected.

Why does the for loop work and the forEach loop not work in this situation?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String S = "hello";
      String curly1 = "{";
      String box1 = "[";
      String p1 = "(";
      String curly2 = "}";
      String box2 = "]";
      String p2 = ")";
               char[] nested = S.toCharArray();
        int flag = 0;

        if(nested[0] != curly1.charAt(0)) flag = 0;
        if(nested[nested.length-1] != curly2.charAt(0)) flag = 0;

        for(char i : nested) {
            if(nested[i] == curly1.charAt(0) && nested[(i+1)] == box1.charAt(0) || nested[i] == box1.charAt(0) && nested[(i+1)] == p1.charAt(0)) {
                flag = 1; }
             else if(nested[i] == p2.charAt(0) && nested[(i+1)] == box2.charAt(0) || nested[i] == box2.charAt(0) && nested[(i+1)] == curly2.charAt(0)) {
                 flag = 1; }
                else { flag = 0;}
        }
        System.out.println(flag);

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think an enhanced for loop works? What value gets bound to `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access something using index in your loop use for, not foreach (enhaced for).

Now you are accessing the `nested` array using variable `i` of type `char`. The variable `i` represents an element of the `nested` array that is being iterated over. So if you access the array using this variable, its value will be implicitly converted to its int representation (for instance `'a' == 97`), which will cause the exception.

In your case you need the for loop, or to keep current index value in some other variable and increment it with each iteration, because you can't do this sort of index arithmetics with enhanced for: `nested[i + 1]`

Comment: but even when I change the char in the foreach loop to an int, it still doesn't work, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop doesn't give you an index, it gives you the elements from the array. So `char i` is one of the `chars` in the array. After that, you say `nested[i]` as if `i` was an index, but it isn't. `chars` have numerical value, but it is likely that the numerical value is larger than the length of your array. Also, with a foreach loop, there is no good way to get the element after the one being iterated on as you are trying to do with `nested[(i+1)]`. Stick to using the normal `for` loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

Its because in for each version you are trying to access array indices by character elements.

for(char i:nested) 
{
   //  here i is a character not an array index so nested[i] is not accessing proper index.
}

Answer (score 0):

The foreach loop delivers characters in i not indexes into the array.
You can't do exactly what you want with this kind of loop because you cannot look-ahead to the next character

```
for(char i : nested) {
   if(i == curly1.charAt(0) && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> In foreach  **for(char i : nested)** loop **i** is element in array not
>   index of array

you can initialize the array index first then increment it in for loop;

```
int index =0;

for(char i : nested) {
   index ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case (`for(int i = 0; i < nested.length; i++)`) the variable `i` is the index of the array.

In the second case you use `forEach` iteration construction which iterates through elements, not through the indexes.

The construction `for(char i : nested)` is misleading because it makes you still think that `i` is the index, while it is not. If you write `for(char element : nested)`, then the code will be clear, and instead of `nested[i]` you should use just `element`.

However, with this approach you will not access the next element in the array (`nested[i+1]`), so this kind of iteration is not appropriate for your case.